# Apache Server with single site, when scanning by IP address it's pulling local certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, linux-networking, configuration

We have a single word press site running on top of Apache on CentOS.  When one of our clients is doing a security scan it's scanning by IP address vs Domain Name and when that happens it's pulling the local certificate vs the certificate for the domain.  Also if I type in the IP and a page that doesn't exist I get the 404 message but with the local certificate.  However if I do the same thing with the domain name it pulls in the correct certificate.
I know it's a configuration issue, I just don't know where to look to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the IP address to your virtual host configuration in addition to the domain name. Then Apache will use the certificate for that block instead the default virtual host.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that is in my eye the answer to the question.